# Determining the kernel of homomorphism of an abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is any abelian group, and let $F$ be a homomorphism from $G$ to $G$ such that $F(x)=x^5$ for all $x$ belonging to $G$. Then find the Kernel of $F$.

Comment: I want to say "elements of order 5."

Comment: What is the definition of kernel? Just apply that.

Comment: @dalbrit almost.

Comment: It's important to be precise and use terms correctly. Groups don't have kernels, homomorphisms do.

Comment: I am really sorry for such a silly mistake!

Comment: @Adimathematica It is good for all of us to become aware of 'silly' mistakes, but don't feel sorry for making them. The fact that you make mistakes is just an indication that you are working (as you should). Others are not bothered by it.

Comment: @ah11950 aha, how could I forget 1...

Answer (score 2):

Because $G$ is abelian, $F$ is indeed a homomorphism, and we have

$$x \in \ker F \iff F(x) = x^5 = 1$$

Hence $\ker F = \{x \in G \mid x^5 = 1\}$ = $\{1\} \sqcup \{x \in G \mid | x|=5\}$. There's not really a great deal more you can say.

By "There's not really a great deal more you can say", I mean that there is no *explicit* description one can give of elements of the kernel without having more information about $G$.

Comment: yaa! I know this answer but I want to find the kernel explicitly.

Comment: See my edit. This isn't possible.

Comment: can anybody give an example of an abelian group having this homomorphism and kernel not equal to {e}??

Comment: Any finite abelian group whose order is divisible by 5 will do. Recall this is equivalent to having an element of order 5, which is equivalent to $F$ having nontrivial kernel.

Comment: ...wich is equivalent to $F$ being not injective.

Comment: I feel like we've come full circle...